# App Store Submission

Tags: iphone, time, app-store, submission

In the real world, how long does it take from submission to acceptance & availabilty for download. My boss wants to figure out a project timeline & I need to give him a time.

Just wanted to get peoples input from their experiences.

Comment: This is not really a programming question. You might try the Apple Developer Forums at http://devforums.apple.com

Comment: Obviously I'm not asking what the idealised time is considering all is perfect on that day & all Apple components involved are in a good mood. More of a realistic time frame to expect.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I just thought there is a crap load of collective experience here, I will ask there.

Comment: For the last few months, I'd say from 4 days to 2 weeks.

Comment: @Spider-Paddy - The problem with a question like this is that the correct answer will change on a regular basis, depending on App Store review traffic.

Comment: @brad - I realise that the question was like asking "how long is a piece of string" but I was just looking for an approximate time frame, i.e. hours, days, weeks or months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under a week as Espuz pointed out. It's worth noting though that they will fail the submission on the first fault they find and not continue any testing.

My first app needed to be resubmitted 3 times with different modifications before it was approved. Also worth noting that you can set 'Validate built product' in the project settings to run the same initial checks that apple does on your app. This will run every time you do a build and warn you of any problems

Comment: Thanks for the validate built product tip, I must remember that.

Answer (score 0):

In my own experience, 4 to 7 days since the submission until the availability, reviewed on USA store and sent from Spain.

Answer (score 0):

My first and only experience... just recently was 8 days from submission to acceptance... this spanned a holiday weekend though... so Possibly could have been quicker if submitted at a different time.